# Xamarin.Forms - ImageButtons in Expander do nothing as they're clicked

Tags: button, xamarin.forms, uicollectionview, expander

So I have a collectionview and inside of that I have an expander with 3 buttons. The problem is that once I touch one of these 3 buttons they don't do nothing even if they're binded to commands.

Here's how it looks like:

[image]
[image]

Here's the code:

```xml
<CollectionView HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" 
                Margin="0,5,20,15"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"
                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
                HeightRequest="210">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Margin="8,0">
                <xct:Expander>
                    <xct:Expander.Header>
                        <Grid RowDefinitions="*,auto">
                            <PanCake:PancakeView Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                                <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding Cover}" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="145" Aspect="Fill"/>
                            </PanCake:PancakeView>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontFamily="Inter" WidthRequest="145" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" MaxLines="2" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </xct:Expander.Header>
                    <xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                <ImageButton Source="trash_24.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="Start" Command="{Binding RemoveBookFromCollection}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                </ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton Source="cross_24.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Command="{Binding SetBookAvailability}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" WidthRequest="24" HeightRequest="24" HorizontalOptions="Start"  Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                </ImageButton>
                                <ImageButton Source="check_24.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Command="{Binding SetBookAvailability}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                </ImageButton>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </xct:Expander.ContentTemplate>
                </xct:Expander>                                   
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataTemplate` has a different `BindingContext` than the rest of the Page. The `DataTemplate` inherits its `BindingContext` from each book instance in the `Books` collection. You need to use a [relative binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings#bind-to-an-ancestor) in your command binding expression, e.g.:

```
Command="{Binding RemoveBookFromCollection, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModel:YourViewModel}}"
```

This will become apparent in the IDE, if you provide the `x:DataType` to the DataTemplate.

You also don't need the *ContentTemplate* for the body of the Expander, since you're directly providing the content yourself.

Since you didn't show the ViewModel, I will use a generic name, so you'll have to adapt it to your needs to make it work:

```xml
<CollectionView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Books}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Book">
            <xct:Expander>
                <xct:Expander.Header>
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,auto">
                        <PanCake:PancakeView Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding Cover}" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="145" Aspect="Fill"/>
                        </PanCake:PancakeView>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontFamily="Inter" WidthRequest="145" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" MaxLines="2" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>
                    </Grid>
                </xct:Expander.Header>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                    <ImageButton
                        Source="trash_24.png"
                        Command="{Binding RemoveBookFromCollection, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModel:YourViewModel}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                    </ImageButton>

                    <!-- etc ... -->

                </StackLayout>
            </xct:Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

The `viewModel:YourViewModel` should of course be replaced with your actual namespace and ViewModel. The namespace needs to be included in the XAML header of your page as an XML namespace (`xmlns`) and ideally also provide the `x:DataType` to the Page in order to use [compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings) which also helps the IDE in pointing out binding issues to you and it will produce compiler errors for faulty binding expressions, e.g.:

```xml
<ContentPage
    xmlns:viewModel="YourProject.SomeFolderWhereTheViewModelExists"
    x:DataType="viewModel:YourViewModel" />
```

Using the compiled bindings and the `x:DataType` attribute is entirely optional, though, but will help with binding expressions.
or similar.